# Why does C# ternary operator require a cast that equivalent if() statement does not?

Tags: c#, casting, ternary-operator

I don't understand why the following two code statements are not equivalent:

```
if( _hexColourString.Length >= 8 )
    _bytes[ 3 ] = byte.Parse( _hexColourString.Substring( start + 6, 2 ), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier );
else
    _bytes[ 3 ] = 0x00;


_bytes[ 3 ] = ( _hexColourString.Length >= 8 ) ? byte.Parse( _hexColourString.Substring( start + 6, 2 ), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier ) : 0x00;
```

The first compiles no problem while the second says that I need to cast an int to a byte. Fixing it is obviously no problem, but I'd like to understand why the cast is necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in the second case, we need to anaylze what the type of the conditional expression is *first*. The two subexpressions are `byte` or `int` (a literal in this case), and so the overall type of this expression is `int`. And it's not a literal at this point, it's a general expression.

We then try to assign this `int` to `_bytes[3]` which can only accept a `byte` and we get an error.

In the first case, we analyze two separate expressions and consider conversions for both separately. There, in the `else`, we have an assignment of a *literal* `int` to a `byte`. That's a special implicit conversion that's only allowed for literal `int`<sup>1</sup>; The conditional expression isn't a literal.

My preferred fix is this:

```
_bytes[ 3 ] = ( _hexColourString.Length >= 8 ) ?
     byte.Parse( _hexColourString.Substring( start + 6, 2 ),NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
   : (byte)0x00;
```

(newlines for readability only)

This now makes the type of the conditional `byte` rather than `int`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This conversion isn't considered when analysing the type of the conditional since we don't need it - we're *always* allowed an implicit conversion from `byte` to `int` so `int` is the best type for the conditional expression.

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you.